# img with {display: table-cell} -- is it a bug?

Tags: css, image, css-tables

I want to use the `display: table-*` CSS properties to format a list of photos. I believe that below is a "correct" implementation of it, in that there's nothing theoretically wrong with it, but it displays in Firefox and Safari with the table layout screwed up, as you can see by the borders. For a comparison, try wrapping both img tags below in a `<div></div>`; this displays properly.

This is something specific to the img tag, perhaps how big it thinks it is versus how much space it actually takes. Is this a bug?

The code below is a minimal provocation of this problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .photos {display: table; border-collapse: collapse;}
            .photos > div {display: table-row}
            .photos > div > * {
                display: table-cell;
                vertical-align: top;
                border: 1px solid #000;
                padding: 10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="photos">
            <div>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <img src="http://www.freeimages.co.uk/galleries/nature/weather/thumbs/frost_oak_leaf_winter_218310.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <img src="http://www.freeimages.co.uk/galleries/nature/weather/thumbs/frost_oak_leaf_winter_218310.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you not want this to work on IE6/7 (or 8 in compat mode)?

Comment: This is not an IE6/7 problem, in fact according to o.k.w. it *only* works nicely in IE, but not in Firefox or Safari, the only two browsers I tested. In Firefox and Safari, the borders on the img table cell are off from the borders of the other table cells.

Comment: At what point would it be appropriate to leave a bug report on Webkit/Firefox? It seems we have reduced the problem to img's rendering as table-cell within a tag rendering as a table with border-collapse: collapse. The problem goes away with separate borders. Is this enough to merit a bug report, or are we not sure yet that this behavior is not compliant with W3C standards and is in fact a bug?

Comment: I did just that https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=537201 but no response yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be mostly due to the border-collapse.  If you remove that, the alignment problem goes away.  I can't seem to find any other discussion of this problem online but I have noticed bugs in the border-collapse: collapse algorithm many times in Firefox and Safari (lines that disappear/reappear as you scroll, etc).  This appears to be just another bug in that algorithm.

You're are right however, that it is specific to the image, if you wrap the images in divs, the problem goes away:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .photos {display: table; border-collapse: collapse;}
        .photos > div {display: table-row; border-collapse: collapse;}
        .photos > div > * {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: top;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="photos">
        <div>
            <p>Hello World</p>
            <div><img src="http://www.studentsoftheworld.info/sites/music/img/23448_shopping_bags1.gif" /></div>
            <p>Hello World</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Hello World</p>
            <div><img src="http://www.studentsoftheworld.info/sites/music/img/23448_shopping_bags1.gif" /></div>
            <p>Hello World</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tested this in Firefox 3.1 in Ubuntu and XP, Firefox 3.5 in XP, Safari 4 in Wine and XP, and Chrome 3 in XP and they ALL exhibit errors in rendering the border-collapse.  Only Firefox shows the image table-cell as one pixel low.

Opera 9.52 in XP oddly does not display the image at all.
Opera 10.10 in XP behaves like the rest.

Perhaps there's something about the spec that causes so many browsers to interpret this way.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you meant when I render the codes in FF. My initial thought was the doctype but it doesn't help with loose, transitional or strict.

Going through a W3C reference at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-display
Here's an excerpt:

> For example, an image that is set to
>   'display: table-cell' will fill the
>   available cell space, and its
>   dimensions might contribute towards
>   the table sizing algorithms, as with
>   an ordinary cell.

Seems to me that non-container elements will just fill the 'cell space' but not acting like a true cells. Which explains the border 'bug'.

I am hesistant to think the FF/Webkit-based browsers are rendering it wrongly but IE is correct. Perhaps someone can prove otherwise. :P

My 2 cents.