# <img> element and display:table-cell

Tags: html, css

I am trying to replace images in a single horizontal row - as cells in a table row.

That layout works with any other elements but not with `<img>` for some reason.

Check this:

```css
div { display: table; border: 1px solid red; }
div > img { display: table-cell; }
```

```html
<p>These shall be replaced in single row but they are not:</p>

<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-78-50-6.jpg" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-78-50-5.jpg" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-78-50-5.jpg" />
</div>
```

Any idea?

UPDATE: FF follows CSS spec and replaces them in single row. All other browsers are not. Heil Firefox!

Comment: What if you just remove `div > img { display: table-cell; }` and allows the images to use the default `inline` display?

Comment: each image on a single row?

Comment: Why not just remove the table and table-cell declarations altogether? Images naturally align as inline elements.

Comment: I'm afraid the only solution that I can come up with is to wrap every image into divs and set `display:table-cell` to those divs

Comment: I concur, example: [codepen](http://codepen.io/sathomas/pen/bVJZBW)

Comment: When set to `display-cell`, each `img` element is computed to be the full width of the table. The table's full width, however, is calculated correctly as three times the width of the images. I don't know why this is the case.

Comment: Your only solution is to wrap your `img`s in divs. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1978293/1891677).

Comment: @StephenThomas `<img>` are treated as if they have display:block; and that happens in all browsers but not in FF. Question is: is there any pec for that?

Comment: The only reference I can find is in the CSS2 spec, and it seems to imply that `display-cell` should work as intended: "For example, an image that is set to 'display: table-cell' will fill the available cell space" [reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-display)  BTW, images are normally `inline`, not `block`

Comment: "... and its dimensions **might** contribute towards the table sizing algorithms, as with an ordinary cell."  It goes on to say: "User agents **may ignore** these 'display' property values for HTML table elements, since HTML tables may be rendered using other algorithms intended for backwards compatible rendering. However, this is not meant to discourage the use of 'display: table' on other, non-table elements in HTML."

Comment: could be a possible bug..see.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977768/img-with-display-table-cell-is-it-a-bug...hmm...why not use a workaround?..perhaps some javascript to take all children elements and placed them each in an inline-block element?....just a thought

Comment: @c-smile Well you take a look at my screwed up [fork](http://codepen.io/01/pen/ojOVwv). I'm not sure why border-spacing is so important, but a 4px border-space is like a 2px margin for each "cell".

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

img is a replaced element, it's measured calculations and box model are different. See this [**ARTICLE**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element)

---

If you insist on using table and are concerned about spacing look at this fork of @[StevenThomas's PenCode](http://codepen.io/01/pen/ojOVwv)

I removed all the divs

```
.container { display: table; table-layout: auto; width: 100%; }

img { display: inline-table; margin: .33em; width: 30%; height: auto; }
```

Use `margin: .125em` if you want 4px; border-spacing.

---

Change div to inline-block

Change img to inline-block

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
div > img {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>These shall be replaced in single row but they are not:</p>

<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-78-50-6.jpg">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-78-50-5.jpg">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-78-50-5.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: This works (as do the other approaches suggested in the comments), but it doesn't answer the OP's question. Why can't you set an `img` to `display-cell`?

Comment: I need them precisely in table row so I can use border-spacing 
that is independent from spaces used in markup.

Comment: I think that placing three images in a row is not the point and OP asked this question because `display:table-cell` doesn't work properly with `img` tags

Comment: btw `font-size: 0` will remove whitespaces

Comment: Add `border-spacing:4px;` at that fork you provided, you will see that images are replaced inside single cell but not as separate cells.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a div, you could try using a table. Here's the syntax:

```
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

The tr tags are rows, the td tags are columns. I'd use this syntax:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-78-50-6.jpg"></td>
<td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-78-50-5.jpg"></td>
<td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-78-50-5.jpg"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        div {
            display: inline-flex;
            border: 1px solid red;             
        } 

        div > img {
            height: 250px;
            width: 250px;
            display: table-cell;
        }
```

**Here,I just replaced display:table to display:inline-flex and this worked for me.**

Comment: "Here,I just replaced display:table to display:inline-flex"

Why do you need `display: table-cell;` then? It should be `display: block;` if you use flexbox there. Yet, why `display: inline-flex;` but not `display: flex;` ?